# SQL Server Check Constraint Using Regex

Tags: sql, sql-server, constraints, check-constraints

I have a column (`RouteUrl`) in a table which contains a string representing a relative url.

An example would be: `/guides/by-topic/the-planet`

However, in some cases, the url could be dynamic, meaning it's partially complete and will be finalised later in code.

An example would be: `/guides/by-topic/{Topic}`

I also have a second column (BIT) (`HasRouteParams`) which indicates whether `RouteUrl` is the former or the latter.

**State 1**

- RouteUrl: /guides/by-topic/the-planet
- HasRouteParams: false (0)

**State 2**

- RouteUrl: /guides/by-topic/{Topic}
- HasRouteParams: true (1)

I need to create a check constraint which forces one or the other. The obvious way is to check for one or preferably a pair of curly brackets.

In simple terms, the SQL equivalent of this:

```
CONSTRAINT [CK_Page_RouteInfo] CHECK (Do something here)

(HasRouteParams = true AND has curly brackets) OR (HasRouteParams = false AND doesn't have curly brackets)
```

However, this is slightly beyond my (very) sparse knowledge of SQL. Any advice appreciated.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have regular expressions. SQL, the language, isn't great at query manipulation to begin with

Comment: Do you mean a constraint where `BIT is not null`? Or `BIT` is not just `HasRouterParams' and could have other information?

Comment: You can create a SQLCLR function to perform regular expression matches, like the one shown [in this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/6529/sql-server-regex-clr-function/). In a SQLCLR function you can also use [Uri.TryCreate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.trycreate?view=net-6.0#system-uri-trycreate(system-string-system-urikind-system-uri@)) to check whether the string is a valid relative URL

Comment: @james I just want to create the appropriate syntax which gives me the expression: if (HasRouteParams = true AND has curly brackets) OR (HasRouteParams = false AND doesn't have curly brackets)

Comment: Rather than a check constraint that ensures the two columns are consistent, would a better option be to have `HasRouteParams` be a *computed* column based on the presence or not of the curly braces in `RouteUrl`. E.g. it appears to be derived data, and you usually shouldn't store derived data.

Comment: If you want to check if a string has a specific character in it, you can use `LIKE` or `CHARINDEX`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The reason for the HasRouteParams column is because additional data is held in other tables for the 'dynamic' curly bracket urls. Yes, I could check to see if the optional data is null, but this seems a cleaner option. Otherwise, I wouldn't know the difference between a non-dynamic url  and a missing row in the additional table.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The computed column sounds interesting (I don't know much about them) but we're back to the same question - how do I detect the curly brackets on the syntax?

Comment: @Larnu LIKE seems a viable option but how do I wildcard it so it can be anywhere within the string? I don't know the position.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/like-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)? It has a table of the wildcards.

Comment: @Larnu I've had a look at the documentation and created what I think is correct but it doesn't work.  CONSTRAINT [CK_Page_RouteType] CHECK ([HasRouteParams] = (1) AND [RouteUrl] LIKE '%{%' OR [HasRouteParams] = (0) AND [RouteUrl] NOT LIKE '%{%'). Any ideas?

Comment: I suggest you change your approach completely. Surely the process that sets this column **knows** if the string is "complete" or "partial". Therefore, it should set the flag.

Comment: @SMor So, whatever's in the code goes? I'm no DB expert, but from what I've read there will be millions of DBA's around the world shouting 'Nooooooooo!!!!' simultaneously :).

Comment: And the DBA has absolutely NO control over what is stored in this column and cannot predict how that format might be changed and DOES NOT actually use the pattern and apply the "variable" part to make a complete URL. Real life is often not pretty.